# Lubuntu 14.04: fatal GDBus Error upon session login

Tags: lubuntu, authentication, policykit

Two days ago I freshly installed a Lubuntu Desktop 14.04 on an old Centrino M with 2 accounts:  uid 1000 (administrator) and uid 1001 (general user)

Until an hour ago all was well. Then shortly after initiating a session for uid 1001, I started getting:

*GDBus.Error:org:FreeDesktop.PolicyKit.1.Error:Failed

An authentication agent already exists for the given subject.*

The small error message window has an "Accept" button, but most of the time I have not enough time to click it, before the session abruptly crashes and the OS presents me with a new login menu.

In 10% of cases it leaves me time to click on accept; the error message disappears, the minimized Skype window expands and blinks a couple of time, before the error message comes back and so on until I close the session, restart or power down, using the user panel.

Logging in as uid 1000 is never a problem, before or after this happens in a uid 1001 session. Note that I have exactly the same Desktop and autostart configurations for both users. Namely I have Skype and Firefox launching upon initiating a session - full stop.

I don't know whether it is related (don't think so) but when this started, from within a perfectly normal uid 1001 session, I was tweaking its Lubuntu *user panel*, namely fiddling with on the advanced config setting: "Window Manager treat user panel as Dock" (or something close, because the OS localization is not English).

Any clue, anybody ? Thanks.